# '*' present in the print statement-PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, community-challenge

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1): 
    print(((10**i -1)//9)*((10**i -1)//9))
print('lol just need to fill one more line to post the question IGNORE IT')
```

What is the meaning of '*' in between `((10**i -1)//9)` and `((10**i -1)//9)` in the above print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first look at what you are printing:

```
((10**i -1)//9)*((10**i -1)//9) 

#that is the math task, from which you are printing the result
```

You asked what `*` means.
This is the multiplication operator...

Let's look at the other things, so you get a better understanding of what is going on

```
result = 10**i - 1
```

Here you are doing 10 to the power of i and then minus one.
The `**` operator means to the power of...

So `2**4` means 2^4 or two to the power of four.

Then you are dividing the result of that task with 9 `(result)//9` 
You are using `//` which is the floor division. This will cut of the decimal place.

The right side after the `*` is just the same as the first one.
You multiply them with the `*` operator.

```
result = (10**i -1)//9
print( result * result ) #Multiplication
```

I hope that this helped you.

Answer (score 4):

**`**`** this means power , for example : `5 ** 2` which mean : `5 squared --> 25`. 
`2 ** 7` which mean : `2 to the power of 7 -- > 128`.

**`//`** this means Floor division - division that results into whole number adjusted to the left in the number line.

For example:

```
x = 15
y = 4
print('x / y =',x/y)   # Output: x / y = 3.75
print('x // y =',x//y) # Output: x // y = 3
print('x ** y =',x**y) # Output: x ** y = 50625
print('x * y =',x*y)   # Output: x * y = 60
```

**Update**

To be more clear :  `*` this means multiplication operator.

Hope that helps you , Good Luck